# Suggestions for good data science certified online courses

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am wondering if someone here can recommend some good data science certified online courses.

A simple google research brings hundreds of online academy and I am lost.

It is been one year since I am working in this field and I want to validate my knowledge and acquire more.

Answer (score 1):

There are many but some of the resources are awesome. One such resource is [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/). This is probably the best resource I have encountered yet.